# Is there any experiment that is sensitive enough to detect the $v/c^2x$ term in the Lorentz transformation?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

The Lorentz transformation derived by Einstein in his 1905 paper is given by:

$x’=\gamma (x-vt) \\$
$t’=\gamma (t-\frac{v}{c^2}x)$

If the term $\frac{v}{c^2}x$ is very small or negligible, then relativity of simultaneity (RoS) cannot be detected and absolute simultaneity (AS) can be assumed. For small values of distance x, the term will be very small, hence difficult to measure.
For the Haefele Keating experiment the distance is about 35183km and the average speed about 149m/s for the Eastward trip.
Hence $ \frac{v}{c^2}x = 0.000000058328087 \\ $ or about 58 nanoseconds (c= 299792458). Hence the effect is certainly large enough to be detected in the H&K experiment, but no such effect due to RoS is reported in the H&K experiment! Hence the H&K experiment is consistent with AS, not RoS.
In the case of GPS satellites, the possible effect of RoS should be even greater. Yet, to my knowledge, Engineers did not include RoS in the calculation of the adjustments made prior to launch. Hence it would again appear that AS (not RoS) is consistent with GPS data.

Comment: first, your equation for $t'$ is missing a $\gamma$ factor.  second, why do you think that no such effect was reported in the H&K experiment? that's exactly what they measured

Comment: “first, your equation for is missing a  factor. “,
Yes, sorry I corrected it. For the H&K experiment $\gamma$ is almost one.

“second, why do you think that no such effect was reported in the H&K experiment? that's exactly what they measured – “,

No, I could not find any reference to RoS in their paper - perhaps you can help me? Do you perhaps see the predicted effect of 58ns for RoS anywhere in their paper?

Comment: The measurement was perfectly consistent with the prediction of special relativity, which as you pointed out implies RoS. There is no special relativity without RoS. I'm not sure what you expect to see in the results that is not there

Comment: “There is no special relativity without RoS. I'm not sure what you expect to see in the results that is not there – “,

As the Lorentz transformation shows, one would expect a time offset of about 58ns due to RoS. This is not observed  in the H&K experiment. Therefore the H&K experiment is consistent with AS, not RoS.

Comment: The 58ns you calculate would be the time difference, in the moving frame, between two events that happened simultaneously in the rest frames, at a distance of 35183km apart from each other. How do you expect the H&K experiment to measure it ? which are those two events ? When you compare theory to experiments, you need to carefully understand the experimental setup and how to translate theoretical predictions to measurements

Comment: “The 58ns you calculate would be the time difference, in the moving frame, between two events that happened simultaneously in the rest frames, at a distance of 35183km apart from each other. “,

Not sure how they can be simultaneous in the rest frame?

“How do you expect the H&K experiment to measure it ? which are those two events ? “,

As mentioned in the question body:

The Lorentz transformation derived by Einstein in his 1905 paper is given by:

$x’=\gamma (x-vt)$
$t’=\gamma (t-\frac{v}{c^2}x)$
So the event of the airplane landing after 35183km at 149m/s would be:

Comment: $t= 35183000/149 seconds = 236127.5167785235 seconds$ or about 65 hours

$t’=\gamma (t-\frac{149}{c^2}35183000)$
In the H&K experiment the difference between the atomic clocks on the ground t and the airplane t’ is reported (kinematical time dilation):

$t’-t=(\gamma -1)t - \gamma \frac{149}{c^2} 35183000 $

$t’-t=(\gamma -1)t - 0,000000058328087 $
Hence the 58ns should show up as a clock offset in the airplane clock - but no such offset was found in the H&K experiment!

Comment: You have misapplied the equation for simultaneity. As @user341440 said, the equation tells you how much the time in one inertial frame varies from the time in another as a function of distance- it is not the formula for time dilation.

Comment: “You have misapplied the equation for simultaneity”,
How? I have applied the Lorentz transformation equations of Einstein in his 1905 paper and calculated that in the H&K experiment you obtain a time offset of about 58ns. Do you perhaps get a different result?

“As @user341440 said, the equation tells you how much the time in one inertial frame varies from the time in another as a function of distance”,
And this is precisely what I calculated, obtaining a result of 58ns! But, as I mentioned, the H&K experiment does not report any such offset!

Comment: “it is not the formula for time dilation. – “,
This is another irrational argument: you are saying that the Lorentz transformation equations have no time dilation (hence length contraction)! Can I quote you on this? Are you ready to publish it in a peer reviewed paper?
You are so desperate to prove your point that you are willing to use any irrational argument. But a scientist is supposed to only use rational arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Tests of the Lorentz transform have been performed frequently, and with high precision, because Lorentz invariance is of such fundamental importance (and because a number of alternative theories to SR and GR predict violations of Lorentz invariance). There is a summary at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_searches_for_Lorentz_violation

So far no violation of Lorentz invariance has been found, i.e. the Lorentz transforms have been found to hold within the limits of experimental error.

Comment: “So far no violation of Lorentz invariance has been found,”,

Unfortunately the tests you mention in
Wikipedia does not include any test of RoS!

“Lorentz violations concern the fundamental predictions of special relativity, such as the principle of relativity, the constancy of the speed of light in all inertial frames of reference, and time dilation, as well as the predictions of the standard model of particle physics. “,

However, as I indicated, the H&K experiment should have found an offset of about 58ns due to RoS. Yet no offset was found!

Comment: …..This indicates that the H&K experiment is consistent with AS, not RoS.

Comment: The RoS is the application of the Lorenz transform to two simultaneous events in one frame- which produces two events at different times in a moving frame. Ergo experimental tests of the Lorenz transform are experimental tests of the RoS.

Comment: The RoS manifests itself in the Lorentz transformation in the $-\frac{v}{c^2} x$ term:

$x’=\gamma (x-vt)$
$t’=\gamma (t-\frac{v}{c^2}x)$

So Event A and B having the same r value will transform to:

$t_A’=\gamma (t_A-\frac{v}{c^2}x_A)$
$t_B’=\gamma (t_B-\frac{v}{c^2}x_B)$

Then $t_A’-t_B’=\gamma (t_A-t_B-\frac{v}{c^2}(x_A-x_B)$
or  $t_A’-t_B’=\gamma (-\frac{v}{c^2}(x_A-x_B)$

As you can see from the above, RoS only manifests itself in the $-\frac{v}{c^2} x$ term. 

In the case of AS (absolute simultaneity), the Absolute Lorentz transformation (ALT) equations will be:

Comment: $x’=\gamma (x-vt)$
$t’=\gamma t$

So  $t_A’-t_B’=0$, hence no RoS!

Comment: “Ergo experimental tests of the Lorenz transform are experimental tests of the RoS”,
No, the experimental tests are also compatible with the ALT (Absolute Lorentz transformation)! There is no experimental test (that I know of) that can distinguish RoS from AS. This is due to the small $-\frac{v}{c^2} x$ term, which would require v close to c and a large distance $x$ to be able to measure it. In most experiments the $-\frac{v}{c^2} x$ term would be negligible and hence AS would be the appropriate interpretation. Unless you can name a specific experiment that can distinguish RoS from AS?

Comment: But the ALT assume that the speed of light varies by direction in moving frames, and that there must be a preferred frame, and that experimental results only agree with the ALT if the Earth is the preferred frame!

Comment: The Wikipeida link I posted lists literally dozens of experiments, and their precision (in some cases very high, e.g. Chou et. al claimed to be able to detect time dilation at speeds of 36 km/h!) Not to mention that some of the experiments are performed in particle accelerators with v very close to c. Relativity is not a new or untested theory; physicists have been testing it for more than a century.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_theories_of_special_relativity and note that the Ives-Stillwell, Kennedy-Thorndike, and Michelson-Morley type experiments all look at variations from the Lorentz transformations of magnitude $\frac{v^2}{c^2}$, and there are currently pretty strict limits on that possible variation.

Comment: “The Wikipeida link I posted lists literally dozens of experiments, and their precision (in some cases very high, e.g. Chou et. al claimed to be able to detect time dilation at speeds of 36 km/h!) “,
As I mentioned to you, the experiments do not measure the $-\frac{v}{c^2} x$ term! So there is not one experiment that can confirm RoS. Something that can’t be measured belongs to Metaphysics, not physics. The simpler assumption (Occam’s razor) is AS.

Comment: “Relativity is not a new or untested theory; physicists have been testing it for more than a century.”,
And all the experiments of special relativity are compatible with LET (Lorentz ether theory) as well! 
Einstein have no references in his 1905 paper, implying that he invented relativity on his own, which is false. Voigt published transformation equations well before and Einstein used the same notation (not that of Lorentz) in his 1905 paper. Yet Einstein gave no credit to Voigt.

Comment: “Michelson-Morley type experiments all look at variations from the Lorentz transformations of magnitude ^2/^2 and there are currently pretty strict limits on that possible variation. “,

This irrational argument clearly shows your desperation. As a scientist, do you not know the difference between ^2/^2 and /^2? To spell it out, suppose v is close to c. Then /^2 is about c times smaller than ^2/^2! So your argument falls flat on it’s face. It also confirms that RoS is an irrational belief of scientists, not a rational fact confirmed by repeated experiments.

Comment: Furthermore, the term you want to measure is actually  /^2 x! So the distance x also becomes important. In the Michelson Morley experiment the distance x is much smaller than in the H&K experiment. So the term /^2  x would require atomic clocks of accuracy much greater than in the H&K experiment. If a physical effect is so small that it can’t be measured, then the simpler assumption is to assume that it does not exist. Hence that AS is always observed, not RoS.